# SSRS 2008 Adding PageBreak Before and within Subreport

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report with a Subreport.  I want to add a pagebreak before the subreport.  Also, the subreport has page breaks within that report but those breaks are not recognized when I run it as a subreport.

I would appreciate any guidance on this?

Answer (score 3):

Add a rectangle between your subreports. Notice you can set page break settings in rectangle.

```
<SubReport1>...</SubReport1>
          <Rectangle Name="RectanglePageBreak">
            <ReportItems>
              <Rectangle Name="RectanglePageBreak2">
                <PageBreak>
                  <BreakLocation>End</BreakLocation>
                </PageBreak>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Height>0.05in</Height>
                <Width>7.9in</Width>
                <Visibility>
                  <Hidden>False</Hidden>
                </Visibility>
                <Style>
                  <Border>
                    <Style>None</Style>
                  </Border>
                </Style>
              </Rectangle>
            </ReportItems>
            <PageBreak>
              <BreakLocation>End</BreakLocation>
            </PageBreak>
            <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            <Top>1.79872in</Top>
            <Height>0.05in</Height>
            <Width>7.9in</Width>
            <ZIndex>2</ZIndex>
            <Visibility>
              <Hidden>False</Hidden>
            </Visibility>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
              </Border>
            </Style>
          </Rectangle>
<SubReport2>...</SubReport2>
```